# Google Map - How to cluster millions of close locations

Tags: dictionary, location, cluster-computing

I have a google map that will show locations like heatmap (each point has color according to some value).

My problem is that for some close points there exists more than `100` locations.
Instead of showing all of these, I need to take some average and show `2` or `3` locations instead of `100`.

My target is like that,
I want to divide the map into squares and each square will show only one point (averages of the locations inside that square).

Is there any idea or algorithm for this situation?